# javascript how to create callable instances

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create instances of functions with augmented prototypes to avoid monkey-patching `Function.prototype` and avoid copying properties to each function instance.

It doesn't seem possible by inheriting the Function prototype though.

```
var util = require('util');
function Fn () {}
util.inherits(Fn, Function);
var fn = new Fn('a', 'return a;');

fn.call(null, 5);
// TypeError: object is not a function

fn.apply(null, [ 5 ]);
// TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic
//     at Fn.toString (native)
```

**Edit**: Why would I want to do that?

Trying to write chainable higher-order functions for dealing with promises.

```
when('  promise').then(library.trim().toUpperCase())
// becomes 'PROMISE'
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more **what** you're trying to accomplish?  I'm not making much sense out of your code.  I do understand what the lines are doing.  But I make little sense out of `Fn` as what seems to be an attempted alias for `Function`.  Is it supposed to be more than that?

Comment: edited. mostly syntax sugar tbh

Comment: I've never seen anything like that done.  But maybe I'm being dense, because I'm still not seeing how it would help with chaining higher order functions.

Comment: Scott, `library.trim()` returns a function and `library.trim().toUpperCase()` returns a new function, specifically the combination of trimming and uppercasing.

Comment: Yes, I understood your chain.  I just didn't see how your alias to `Function` helps you achieve it.  Do you have a (even partially working) implementation somewhere?

Comment: Yeah https://github.com/aj0strow/sash. It works by binding the scope, but I have to copy over descriptors on each call

Comment: I'm going to have to dig into that code.  I'm also in the midst of a project that I think of as a more refined utility library, in my case a straightforward functional programming one: https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda.  I'll be interested to see how you do things differently.  I'm afraid I still have no answers for your original question, though.

Comment: cool library! must be doing some interesting projects, not sure when i'd use half the methods myself

Comment: Ok, well I've looked at it enough to understand **why** you want to do what you're trying to do.  I've tried a few approaches, with no success.  I'm not yet convinced it's impossible, but I wouldn't be surprised.  This is an interesting approach.  My library uses a more traditional FP approach using lots of composition and liberal currying, with some attempt to go points-free when possible (e.g. sum can be defined simply as `reduce(add, 0)`.)  I could see some nice things from your approach if you can get it to work.

Comment: Oh, and all those functions are ones that either my co-writer or I have found useful in the past year.  Of course both of us are full-time JS people these days, and both interested in functional programming, so we tend to think in these terms.

Comment: yea read your code. really enjoyed that curry calls itself, definitely cleaner than overloading `bind`